# how to find the numbers of all curves

Tags: r

I have a data which looks like the following

```
## the same as: sf <- spectrum((AirPassengers), spans = c(3, 3), plot = FALSE)
sf <- spec.pgram((AirPassengers), spans = c(3, 3), plot = FALSE)
x <- sf$freq
y <- log(sf$spec)
plot(x, y, type="l", col="red" )
```

I want to find:

- the number of curve that are in this data (in this case 5)
- the beginning value that the curve start and the end value that a curve finishes.

Comment: what do you mean by "the number of curves"? the number and position of local maxima?

Answer (score 1):

```
i <- which(diff(sign(diff(y)))<0)+1L;
length(i); ## number of local maxima
## [1] 5
i; ## indexes of local maxima
## [1] 12 24 36 48 60
```

---

Of course, the same can be done for the local minima by reversing the comparison:

```
j <- which(diff(sign(diff(y)))>0)+1L;
length(j); ## number of local minima
## [1] 6
j; ## indexes of local minima
## [1]  7 18 30 41 53 71
```

---

You can plot points at the local maxima and minima easily as follows:

```
points(x[i],y[i]);
points(x[j],y[j]);
```

[image: plot]

---

Based on the wording of your question, I suspect you actually want the 5 segments that are delimited by the 6 local minima. Thus `j` is your guy. (You can use either `length(i)` or `length(j)-1L` to get the count of segments.)

Comment: thanks, this is quite the answer ! however, what i want is to find the index for each peak so that i can manipulate (shrunk/strach ) between each two or pairs of peaks. look at this question I have asked days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617392/find-the-best-match-between-two-data-frame